# How to remove surrounding quotes (") while using <%= %> in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails application which has **toinsert** as column names of one of the tables that has a whole div element stored in it. I want to insert that element using jquery in HTML DOM to an element with class '**map**'. I am making an AJAX call and using this:

```
$('.map').html('<%= @dataextracted.toinsert %>');
```

but instead of this:

```
<div class='map'>
  <div class='fromdatabase'></div>
</div>
```

It does the below:

```
<div class='map'>
  "<div class='fromdatabase'></div>"
</div>
```

So Element **gets inserted as a string**. I thought <%= %> might be creating problems so  I wrote the following..

```
$('.map').html('<%= @dataextracted.toinsert %>'.substring(1, '<%= @dataextracted.toinsert %>'.length-2));
```

But instead of removing quotes (") from it, it remove the opening and closing tags of div element (<>).

Also would like to mention that **hardcoding it directly works fine** (did it just for debugging).

```
$('.map').html('<div class="fromdatabase"></div>');
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) method as following.

```js
$('.map').html("<%= @dataextracted.toinsert.html_safe %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of @dataextracted.toinsert also has single quotes in it, it might have something to do with quoting. Try using double quotes:

```
$('.map').html("<%= @dataextracted.toinsert %>");
```